# How two add line from point A to B

Tags: c#, sharpmap, nettopologysuite

I am trying to draw a line between two lines.

I could create points by using the createPoint Method

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GeoAPI.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using SharpMap.Layers;
using SharpMap.Data;
using SharpMap.Styles;
using SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics;
using BruTile.Web;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties;

#if DotSpatialProjections
using GeometryTransform = DotSpatial.Projections.GeometryTransform;
#else
using GeometryTransform = GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.GeometryTransform;
#endif

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer : Form
    {

        private List<IGeometry> geos = new List<IGeometry>();


        GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate position, position1,position2;

        public FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.UpdateStyles();
        }

        private void FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Lisbon...
#if DotSpatialProjections
            var mathTransform = LayerTools.Wgs84toGoogleMercator;
            var geom = GeometryTransform.TransformBox(
                new Envelope(-9.205626, -9.123736, 38.690993, 38.740837),
                mathTransform.Source, mathTransform.Target);
#else



            var mathTransform = LayerTools.Wgs84toGoogleMercator.MathTransform;
            GeoAPI.Geometries.Envelope geom = GeometryTransform.TransformBox(
                new Envelope(139.921875, -32.34375 , 5576031.87584, -3808518.221266), mathTransform);

#endif


            //Google Background
            TileAsyncLayer layer2 = new TileAsyncLayer(new OsmTileSource(), "TileLayer - OSM");
            this.mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(layer2);
            var gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 3857);


            //Adds a static layer
            var staticLayer = new VectorLayer("Fixed Marker");
            //position = geom.GetCentroid();
            var aux = new List<IGeometry>();

           // position2 = new Coordinate(-10, -10);
            aux.Add(gf.CreatePoint(geom.Centre));        
            staticLayer.Style.Symbol = Resources.PumpSmall;
            var geoProviderFixed = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(aux);
            staticLayer.DataSource = geoProviderFixed;
            this.mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(staticLayer);
            position = geom.Centre;         



            //Adds a moving variable layer
            VectorLayer pushPinLayer = new VectorLayer("PushPins");
            position1 = new Coordinate(10, 10); 
            geos.Add(gf.CreatePoint(position1));

  // Line Between Two Points


            aux.Add(gf.CreateLineString(10,10,20,20));   



            //

            pushPinLayer.Style.Symbol = Resources.ZoomToExtents1;

            var geoProvider = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(geos);
            pushPinLayer.DataSource = geoProvider;
            this.mapBox1.Map.VariableLayers.Add(pushPinLayer);

            this.mapBox1.Map.ZoomToBox(geom);
            this.mapBox1.Refresh();

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            position1.X = position1.X + (position.X - position1.X)*0.002f;
            position1.Y = position1.Y + (position.Y - position1.Y) * 0.002f;
            VariableLayerCollection.TouchTimer();           

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = false;
        }


        private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mapBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to make the line

I tried this line of code but it returns an error, I just don't know what the parameters are

```
 aux.Add(gf.CreateLineString(10,10, 20,20);
```

> Error 1   No overload for method 'CreateLineString' takes 4
>   arguments D:\Moving object

Comment: Just another incomplete duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162039/how-do-i-draw-a-polygon-using-sharp-map Once again, please at least show us the error. Just cut-n-paste it!

Comment: @BradHards I am sorry i  am pretty new to this  . In this case gf.CreateLineString(10,10,20,20)->Error 1 No overload for method 'CreateLineString' takes 4 arguments

Comment: @BradHards do you know how to draw line ?

Comment: You have tags for [tag:sharpmap] and [tag:nettopologysuite] but your question makes no mention of using either.  For some tips on how to structure a question I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CreateLineString` method only takes one argument - an array of `Coordinate` (strictly speaking an `IEnumerable<ICoordinate>` or an `ICoordinateSequence`). You can see [this in the examples](https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Add%20a%20primitive%20geometry):

```
//Add a LineString with 2 Points
GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate[] points = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate 
    {
        new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(10, 10), 
        new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(20, 20), 
    };

geomColl.Add(gf.CreateLineString(points));
```

Note that there are some API differences across versions, so next time, posting exact version information might be useful.